# Pagination based on time

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, where-clause, date-arithmetic

I have a PostgreSQL database with posts and I am trying to implement pagination for it.

The table looks like this:

`postid | title | author | created`
where created has the type `timestamp without timezone`.

My query looks like

```sql
SELECT * from posts 
WHERE extract(EPOCH FROM created) < :limit
ORDER BY created DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Here `:limit` is a long in java which I pass as a parameter.

However, I always retrieve the same three newest posts, even if I have a limit smaller than the timestamp of the three posts. So I guess that the `extract(EPOCH FROM created)` part is wrong but I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: Is :limit in seconds or milliseconds or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine, and should do what you want, provided that `:limit` is really what you think it is.

I would, however, suggest moving the conversion to the right operand rather than converting the stored value to epoch. This is much more efficient, and may take advantage of an index on the timestamp column:

```
SELECT * 
from posts 
WHERE created < date'1970-01-01' + :limit * interval '1 second'
ORDER BY created DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Or:

```
WHERE created < to_timestamp(:limit::bigint)
```

A possible problem is that `:limit` is given in milliseconds rather than seconds. If so:

```
WHERE created < to_timestamp((:limit/1000)::bigint)
```